# What's the fastest way to determine a full URL from a relative URL (given a base URL)

Tags: regex, performance, perl, uri, perl-module

I'm currently using the module `URI::URL` to generate a full URL from a relative URL; however, it isn't running as fast as I'd like it to be. Does anyone know another way to do this that may be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work.

```
$uri = URI->new_abs( $str, $base_uri )
```

You should also take a look at [the URI page on search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm).

Answer (score 4):

Just happened across [this article](http://blog.vipul.net/2008/08/24/redhat-perl-what-a-tragedy/) which point out shortcomings in Redhat/Centos/Fedora implementations of Perl which affect `URI` profoundly.

If you are running one of these Linux flavours, you might want to recompile Perl from original source (not RPM source).

> I realized that anyone running perl code with the distribution perl interpretter on Redhat 5.2, Centos 5.2 or Fedora 9 is likely a victim. Yes, even if your code doesn’t use the fancy bless/overload idiom, many CPAN modules do!  This google search shows 1500+ modules use the bless/overload idiom and they include some really popular ones like URI, JSON. ...
>
> ... At this point, I decided to recompile perl from source.  The bug was gone.  And the difference was appalling.  Everything got seriously fast.  CPUs were chilling at a loadavg below 0.10 and we were processing data 100x to 1000x faster!

Answer (score 1):

Brendan, I should have clarified that I can't guarantee what the relative path is going to look like. It could be pretty tricky (e.g. has a slash at the front, doesn't have a slash, has "../", etc).

Peter, that's what I'm using now. Or is that faster then using the URI::URL->new($path)->abs?

Answer (score 1):

Could depend a bit how you obtain those 2 strings. Probably the secure, fireproof way to do that is what is in URI::URL or similar libraries, where all alternatives, including malicious ones, would be considered. Maybe slower, but in some environments faster will be the speed of a bullet going to your own foot.

But if you expect there something plain and not tricky could see if it starts with /, chains of ../, or any other char. The 1st would put the server name + the url, the 2nd chop paths from the base uri till getting in one of the other 2 alternatives, or just add it to the base url.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I got the wrong end of the stick but wouldn't,

```
$full_url = $base_url . $relative_url
```

work? IIRC Perl text processing is pretty quick.

*@lennysan* Ah sure yes of course. Sorry I can't help, my Perl is pretty rusty.